# Passing form information to another page even when loaded through JS to a div

Tags: php, jquery, forms, html

So I'm recycling a nice simple e-mail contact form that I have from other sites:

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:loadContent('#bodyContent','/wp-content/themes/GenomeStudios2013/sendmail.php');"> <!--javascript:loadContent('#rightColumn', 'sendmail.php');-->
                    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                    <br /><br />
                    <p><font color="red">*</font>Name:</p>
                    <p><input name="name" type="text" cols="30" /></p>
                    <br />
                    <p><font color="red">*</font>Email:</p>
                    <p><input name="email" type="text" cols="30" /></p>
                    <br />
                    <p>Contact Topic:</p>
                    <select name="topic">
                        <option value="Feedback">Feedback</option>
                        <option value="Bug Report">Bug Report</option>
                        <option value="Press">Press</option>
                        <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
                        <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Job Information">Job Information</option>
                    </select>
                    <br /><br />
                    <p><font color="red">*</font>Message:</p>
                    <p><textarea name="messageBox" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></p>
                    <br />
                    <p>Would you like to recieve a reply?</p>
                    <p>Yes:<input type="radio" name="reply" value="yes"/> No:<input type="radio" name="reply" value="no"/></p>
                    <br />
                    <p><input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Send" /></p>
```

But I'm now trying to load the result page into the div that this page was loaded in instead of reloading the whole page. This however doesn't allow the form to pass the field information to the 2nd page to process.

I've tested it and all I get is a blank e-mail.

Is there a way to pass that info through to the 2nd page even though javascript is loading it instead of a full page load?

Answer (score 0):

loadContent - is not native js function, you need check did you copy from that site the script with the function "loadContent"

But, I see you use WP, then I would advise use cforms-plagin it has GPL and easy to use for create forms